# Не закрывается выпадающее меню по клику вне

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть инпут, по клику на который под ним появляется выпадающее меню. Если нажать на инпут ещё раз, то выпадающее меню закроется. Хочу сделать так, чтобы выпадающее меня закрывалось ещё и если нажать вне самого выпадающего меню или вне инпута, но что-то не получается.

```
$(() => {
    let dropdown = $('.passengers-main-dropdown');

    dropdown.on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).nextAll('.dropdown-box').toggleClass('active');
    });

    $('body').on('click', function(e){
        let drop = $('.dropdown-box');
        if(dropdown.is(e.target) && !dropdown.has(e.target) && drop.has(e.target)) {
            drop.removeClass('active');
            dropdown.removeClass('active');
        }
    })
});
```

Похоже, я что-то путаю с `event`.

Answer (score 1):

https://api.jquery.com/has/

Вы "что-то путаете" с `$().has`. Эта функция возвращает обертку jQuery, то есть в булевском смысле всегда `true`.

```
if (dropdown.is(e.target) && 
    dropdown.has(e.target).length == 0 && 
    drop.has(e.target).length == 0) {
```

Comment: Теперь выпадающее меню вообще не появляется.